# Construct the DFA of the language

Tags: computability, automata, regular-language

I have to construct a DFA for the language $$\{w \mid w \text{ has exactly two } a's \text{ and at leat two } b's\}$$

To construct it we have to construct first the DFA's for the languages $$\{ w \mid \text{ has exactly two } a's\}$$ and $$\{w \mid w \text{ has at least two } b's\}$$

right?? I tried to construct these two DFA's...

For the language $\{ w \mid \text{ has exactly two } a's\}$ I got the following:

[image]

But as it is right now it isn't a DFA, but a NFA...

What is $\delta (q_3, a)$ ??

For the language $\{w \mid w \text{ has at least two } b's\}$ I got the following:

[image]

Is this correct??

To construct now the DFA of the initial language do we take the intersection of the two DFA's ??
$$$$

**EDIT:**

$q_i$ are the state of the DFA of the language $\{ w \mid \text{ has exactly two } a's\}$ and $q_i'$ are the states of the DFA of the language $\{w \mid w \text{ has at least two } b's\}$.

[image]

Comment: You should find out that there's such a thing as \mid in MathJax and LaTeX.  I've edited your question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok... I will take it into consideration... @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, add a non-accepting state $q_4$ to your first automaton; $\delta(q_3,a)=q_4$, and $\delta(q_4,a)=\delta(q_4,b)=q_4$. (I think of this kind of state as a *garbage* or *dump* state; I’ve seen it called a *trap* state and a *dead* state.)

If you know how to combine two DFAs to build one that accepts the intersection of their languages, then yes, you can apply that algorithm to build the desired DFA: the language that you want is the intersection of the two simpler languages. If you have questions about that algorithm, let me know where you’re having trouble.

**Added:** Your combined DFA isn’t quite right. Notice that it doesn’t accept $aabb$: you end up at $\langle q_4,q_3'\rangle$. The problem is that you misdirected the $b$ transitions out of the $\langle q_3,q_k'\rangle$ states. If you check the small DFAs, you’ll see that you should have

$$\langle q_3,q_1'\rangle\overset{b}\longrightarrow\langle q_3,q_2'\rangle\overset{b}\longrightarrow\langle q_3,q_3'\rangle\;,$$

with a $b$ transition from $\langle q_3,q_3'\rangle$ to itself. Remember, each transition in this DFA should mimic transitions in the two small ones: $\langle q_i,q_j'\rangle$ goes to $\langle q_k,q_\ell'\rangle$ on input $x$ if your first DFA goes from $q_i$ to $q_k$ on input $x$ and your second from $q_j'$ to $q_\ell'$ on input $x$.

Otherwise it’s fine, though if you wished to do so, you could combine the three $q_4$ states at the bottom into a single trap state: anything that reaches any one of them eventually ends up trapped at $\langle q_4,q_3'\rangle$ without being accepted.

Comment: I added at my initial post the DFA I constructed for the intersection. Could you tell me if it is correct??

Comment: @MaryStar: Close, but not quite: see the addition to my answer.